# Why is $\mathcal{C}=\{\{ X_T \in A \} \text{ or } \{ X_T \in A \} \cup \{T=\infty \},A \in \mathcal{B}(R) \}$ closed under complementation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Why is $\mathcal{C}=\{\{ X_T \in A \} \text{ or } \{ X_T  \in A\} \cup \{T=\infty \},A \in \mathcal{B}(R) \}$ closed under complementation where  X is a random measurable process and T a random time?

This is (Problem 1.17) in Karatzas and Shreve.

**My problem**: 
If I choose $D=\{ X_T \in A \}$  then clearly $D^c=\{ X_T \in A^c \} \in C$ but when D is of the form $D=\{ X_T \in A \} \cup \{T=\infty \}$ then $D^c=\{ X_T \in A^c\} \cap \{T< \infty \}$ which I cant show is in $\mathcal{C}$

Can you please help?

Comment: You seem to write $\{A \in X_T\}$ for $\{X_T \in A\}$. Is that right or am I misunderstanding your notations?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am sorry, I just fixed it

Comment: Can you define introduced variables, please? especially the $X_{\infty}$.

Comment: @mike239x $X_{\infty}$ is the limit of  random variables $X_t$ whenever it exists. And T is a measurable random variable

Comment: Is there no extra info, like that $T$  is actually a stopping time?

Comment: @GabrielRomon but to prove that it’s a sub sigma algebra I need to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under complementation right ? The rest are easy to show but this is not clear

Comment: @mike239x no it’s not given to be a stopping time . Only a measurable random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of the problem is:

> Prove that 
>   $\{\{X_T\in A\}, A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}\cup\{\{X_T\in A\}\cup \{T=\infty\}, A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field.

In the book, $X_T$ is defined only on $\{T<\infty\}$, so that $\{X_T\in A\}$ should be understood as $\{w\in\{T<\infty\}, X_T(w)\in A \}$.

- $\Omega$ is in the collection: simply note that $\{X_T\in \mathbb R\}\cup \{T=\infty\} = \Omega$
- The collection is closed under complementation:

  1. $\{X_T\in A\}^c = \{T=\infty\}\cup \{X_T\in A^c\}$
  2. $(\{X_T\in A\} \cup \{T=\infty\})^c =  \{X_T\in A\}^c\cap \{T<\infty\} = \{X_T\in A^c\}$
- The collection is closed under countable union: I leave it to you.

Comment: The book says that we define the function $X_T$ on the event $\{T < \infty\}$ but does that imply that event $\{T<\infty\}=\Omega$

Comment: @user3503589 no, and that's the whole point of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

OK so we want to examine the complement of $D = \{X_T\in A\}\cup \{T = \infty\}$, which is
\begin{align*}
D^C = \{X_T\in A\}^C\cap \{T = \infty\}^C \\
= \{X_T\not\in A\}\cap \{T < \infty\}\\
= \{X_T\in A^C\}\cap \{T <\infty\}\\
= \{X_T\in A^C\} = \{X_T\in A'\}
\end{align*}
where we let $A' = A^C$. The last part here should mean we are done. We know that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed under complementation, so $A^C\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, meaning that $D^C = \{X_T\in A'\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: There is still a typo in the statement of the problem/question, by the way. There's still another $\{A\in X_T\}$ which needs to be fixed.

Comment: We don’t know that the set $\{T \leq \infty\}=\Omega$

Comment: Do you not have that $\{X_T\in A'\}\subset \{T < \infty\}$, at least? It's a bit hard to chat about this, because you haven't really specified...any of your notation for anyone who hasn't already read Karatzas and Shreve.

Comment: But still... I imagine you might be able to break things down into cases. Case 1 is that $\infty\in A$, in which case $\infty\not\in A^C$, so $\{X_T\in A^C\}\cap \{T < \infty\} = A^C$. Case 2 is that $\infty\not\in A$, so $\infty\in A^C$, in which case $\{X_T\in A^C\}\cap \{T < \infty\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: I apologize for the missing notation. But T is random time which is a measurable random variable and X is a measurable random process. Is there anything specific you would like to know?

Comment: I don't think we know that $\{X_T \in A'\} \subset \{T< \infty\}$. I actually feel the same about this problem in particular that there might be too little information to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under complementation